# Microsoft Exchange Server - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, exchange-server

My configuration for sending mails in Thunderbird for this exchange server email account is as follows:
server name: pod51003.outlook.com
port: 587
username: my email address
authentication method: normal password
connection security: STARTTLS

I am trying to send email from my rails application, my configuration in my application is as follows:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
address: "pod51003.outlook.com",
port: 587,
authentication: "plain",
:enable_starttls_auto => 'true',
user_name: 'myemail',
password: 'mypassword'
}
```

I have tried different authentication methods such as none and login. I have tried the gem ruby-ntlm and set ntlm as the authentication method too but I keep getting the error:

504 5.7.4 Unrecognized authentication type

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `authentication` setting to `:login`